# Javascript for-loop variable scope?

Tags: javascript

I am from C++ background and new to java script and having difficulty understand for loop scope. What is the scope of variable initialized inside for loop.

```js
//Setup
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
  for(var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
      if(contacts[i].firstName==firstName){
          if(contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return contacts[i][prop];
          else
             return "No such property";
        }
    }
  
    if (i === contacts.length)
    return "No such contact";

}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

I am confused how  `if (i === contacts.length)` variable "i" is used outside for loop, variable "i" is initialize inside for loop and if statement is written  out of scope of for loop. Value of `document.write(i)` is equal to 4 when printed outside loop.Can somebody please explain this?

Comment: The scope of variable declared with 'for loop', is limited within the loop only. You cant access the for loop 'i' variable outside the scope.

Comment: Seriously, @AkshayChawla run this code for yourself.

Comment: Was unaware of this thing. This is great one :) Its limited to function.

Comment: The scope of `var` is as described in all known JS tutorials, intros, documentation pages, and specs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before ECMAScript 6, javascript only supports **function scoping**. A variable declared inside a function is visible anywhere inside that function. Even this:

```js
function foo() {
  if(true) {
    if(true) {
      var v = 7;
    }
  }

  console.log(v); // 7
}
foo();
```

ECMAScript 6 introduced a new way of declaring variables using `let` which respects block scopes. So:

```js
function foo() {
  if (true) {
    if (true) {
      let v = 7;
    }
  }

  console.log(v); // error
}
foo();
```

Comment: But var in ECMA Script 6 doesn't respect the scope of variable. It meant once I declare a variable at any point in function, I will always be able to use that variable anywhere outside the scope of variable?

Comment: @Priyansh As I said the only scope when using `var` is the function scope. Even in ES 6 declaring with `var` will make the variable visible from anywhere inside that function as long as you don't enter the scope of some other function.

Comment: @Priyansh nope its in its *function scope* and its only accessible there

Comment: @Jonas but I initialized it in for loop and keeping C++ perspective variable "I" is out of scope. Is scopes are different in Javascript

Comment: @Priyansh C++ have block scopes, JS doesn't

Comment: @Priyansh yes. Have a look at *hoisting* . In fact it is declared at the beginning of the function with the value of *undefined* : Its then assigned to 0 at the beginning of the for loop... i think you should use *let* instead of *var* as it uses block scoping, just like in C++

Comment: @Jonasw hoisting is another story.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yep but it makes it easier to understand scoping in js in my opinion

Comment: *javascript only supports function scoping* Incorrect. In `catch (e) { }`, `e` is scoped only to the catch block.

Answer (score 2):

`var` scopes a variable to the current *function*, not the current block (unlike `let`).